# Docusign Composite Template display order

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusign-sdk

Can anybody help me to set document display order on composite template method in Docusign?

I have tried sequence option in it but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the example Definition in [Applying documents and attributes with composite template elements]  [1]: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/ ,  This guideline highlights that when you're working with composite templates, where you have a combination of document, server, and inline templates, each of these composite templates should contribute only one document. You should get this document from either the element's document field or the serverTemplate.

Thanks
Sai

Comment: Hai Sai,
`"compositeTemplates": [
  {
    "document": {"name":"Terms and conditons"},
    "serverTemplates": [{...}],
    "inlineTemplates": [{...}]
  },{
    "document": {"name":"Lease Agrement"},
    "serverTemplates": [{...}],
    "inlineTemplates": [{...}]
  }
]`
From the above one how i can Lease Agreement first in sequence and Terms and conditions second?

Answer (score -1):

In the compositeTemplates, the sequence determines the order in which the server and/ or inline templates are applied to the individual document. That means it is used within given document for example Lease Agreement. To prioritize the Lease Agreement as the first document and the Terms and Conditions as the second, you should rearrange the document set as follows:

"compositeTemplates": [ { "document": {"name":"Lease Agrement"}, "serverTemplates": [{...}], "inlineTemplates": [{...}] },{ "document": {"name":"terms and conditions"}, "serverTemplates": [{...}], "inlineTemplates": [{...}] } ]

Please reach out to https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US if you still have questions.  Thankyou sai

Comment: Hello Akhil, could you please share me with your payload?